# Прошу помощи в решение с гуглокартами в выводе координат с переменной для маркера

Tags: javascript, php

Добрый день старшие товарищи - с гугл-картами работаю в первый раз (с целью изучения) прошу помощи в решении моей не большой трудности - мне нужно как-то в переменную "lat" и "lng" присвоить значения из нижнего куска кода переменных "b" и "c" в которых хранятся координаты взятые из txt файла с сервера - заранее благодарю за посильную помощь.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
<script>
var lat = 49.99166487;
var lng = 36.23208189;
function myMap() {
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(49.99166487, 36.23208189);
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 11};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

var semsem = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:semsem});
marker.setMap(map);
} 
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$str=array();
$str=file('77.txt');
for($i=0; $i<count($str); $i++)
{
$pieces = explode(" ", $str[$i]);
$a = $pieces[0];
$b = $pieces[1];
$c = $pieces[2];
echo ("$a" . " " . " " . "$b" . " " . "$c");

}
?>
<script>
var b = <?php echo json_encode("$b", JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>; //Don't forget the 
extra semicolon!
var c = <?php echo json_encode("$c", JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;

</script>
```

Comment: это все один файл ?

Comment: да - это один файл

Comment: Перенести код php в самое начало и просто поменяй `var lat = 49.99166487;` на `var lat = <?php echo json_encode("$b", JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;` и так же с lng

Comment: Да все заработало - спасибо вам огромное)))))))))))